# Issue with struct bit values in c

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation, bit

Hi I am trying to convert a decimal value to binary in c using struct. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct binary{
    int bin:1 ;
};
void main(void){
    int dec = 24;
    struct binary bi[32];
    //printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct binary));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++){
        int k = dec & 1;
        bi[i].bin = k;
        dec = dec >> 1;
        //printf("%d ",k);
    }
    for(int i = 31 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        printf("%d ",bi[i].bin);
    }
}
```

When I print the values I see -1 in place of 1 in the bit fields (0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_000-1_-1000). Can someone know why is this happening? and also I thought the size of struct is 1 bit but when I do the sizeof(struct binary) it shows as 4 bytes do you know why?

TIA

Comment: @sandywho Use unsigned int bin:1 ;

Comment: `int bin:1;` means you use only 1 bit signed value. The compiler will keep it in integer size memory. To get 1 and not -1, define bit as `unsigned bin : 1;`

Comment: @ sandywho What value did you get when you printed the `sizeof(struct binary)`? And what size do you get if you print `sizeof(bi)`?

Comment: There's no advantage to using a structure for this, as opposed to just an `int` or `unsigned int` array, since `sizeof(struct binary)` is just going to be `sizeof(int)` due to structure padding.

Comment: @user3386109 4 and 128 respectively

Comment: @sandywho Yup, so my advice is the same as the accepted answer: don't use bit-fields. In this case, it would take less code and less memory to simply use an array of `char` to store the zeros and ones. Of course, as the answer points out, there no need to store the individual bits at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a 1 bit large bit-field is pretty pointless and also poorly defined by the standard. Most aspects of bit-fields are not specified, including whether an `int` bit-field should count as signed or unsigned. Best advice is to stay 100% clear of bit-fields, particularly when dealing with binary memory mapping.

Notably, you aren't actually converting anything - you are merely copying a 32 bit int bit-by-bit, where you could have copied the whole 32 bits at once. Since all data in your program is already in binary form, there is no need to convert anything. Simply adjust the print routine:

```
uint32_t dec = 0xDEADBEEF;
const size_t bits = 8*sizeof(dec);
for(size_t i=0; i<bits; i++)
{
  uint32_t mask = (1u << (bits-i-1));  // mask from MSB to LSB
  printf("%d", (_Bool)(dec & mask));   // convert zero/non-zero value into 0 or 1
}
```

Output:

```
11011110101011011011111011101111
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using int which is signed and has one bit allocated for denoting sign.

You should use unsigned int e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct binary{
    unsigned int bin:1 ;
};
void main(void){
    int dec = 24; 
    struct binary bi[32];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++){
        int k = dec & 1;
        bi[i].bin = k;
        dec = dec >> 1;

    }   
    for(int i = 31 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        printf("%u ",bi[i].bin);
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is not defined by the standard if an `int` bit-field is signed or unsigned. It may very well be regarded as unsigned - we can't know, because bit-fields are so poorly defined by the standard.